# UIScrollview storyboard

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I'm trying to inplement a UIScrollView for buttons and stuff like this. I am doing it graphically with storyboard but when i run the app it doesn't scroll. What can be my problem and do you know any tutorials about UIScrollView implementing in storyboard not for images, but for buttons, labels 'n stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write code that sets your scroll view's `contentSize` property to something larger than its `bounds.size` to make it scroll.  You can't set `contentSize` in the storyboard, and it doesn't automatically set its own `contentSize`.

Answer (score 6):

As a follow-up be sure to set the contentSize in viewDidAppear rather than viewDidLoad